# Issue Compounding the Value of a Variable in Pine-Script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to write an If Else statement in TradingView's Pine-script that allows the value of a variable from one bar back in the series to be added onto the current value if the conditions are met. This should allow the value of the variable "hd1" to compound until the If condition isn't met.

This is what I have so far:

```
hd1 = if (hl < hl[3]) or (hl < hl[1])
    (hl[1] - hl) + hd1[1]
else 
    0
```

I tried to compound the value with  **+ hd1[1]**  in the code but I get an error that I am not able to reference hd1 until it is defined, which I understand but am unsure how to work around. Is there another way I could approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare variables before hand if you plan on self referencing them. In this case, most likely you'll be able to declare `hd1` with the value of zero.

```
float hd1 = 0
if hl < hl[3] or hl < hl[1]
     hd1 := (hl[1] - hl) + hd1[1]
```

In this case the `else` portion of the `if` statement is unnecessary as `hd1`'s default value is already set to zero in the declaration and would only be modified if the `if` condition is true.